# Excluding 'None' when checking for 'NaN' values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I'm cleaning a dataset of `NaN` to run linear regression on it, in the process, I replaced some`NaN` with `None`.
After doing this I check for remaining columns with `NaN` values using the following code, where `houseprice` is the name of the dataframe

```
def cols_NaN():
    return houseprice.columns[houseprice.isnull().any()].tolist()
print houseprice[cols_NaN()].isnull().sum()
```

the problem is that the result of the above includes `None` values also. I want to select those columns which have `NaN` values. How can I do that?

Comment: Both `NaN` and `None` resolve to null according to `isnull()`  You're probably better off tracking the intermediate replacements in another series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For working with column names it is a bit different, because need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`pandas.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

For `houseprice.columns.apply()` and if `houseprice.columns.isnull()` get errors:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'
>
> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'isnull'

```
houseprice = pd.DataFrame(columns = [np.nan, None, 'a'])

print (houseprice)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [nan, None, a]

print (houseprice.columns[(houseprice.columns.map(type) == float) & 
                          (pd.isnull(houseprice.columns))].tolist())
[nan]
```

And for check all values in `DataFrame` is necessary [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
houseprice = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[np.nan,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':['a','s',None],
                   'F':[np.nan,4,3]})

print (houseprice)
   A  B    C  D     E    F
0  1  4  NaN  1     a  NaN
1  2  5  8.0  3     s  4.0
2  3  6  9.0  5  None  3.0

print (houseprice.columns[(houseprice.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, float)) & 
                           houseprice.isnull()).any()])
Index(['C', 'F'], dtype='object')
```

And for sum this code is simplier - [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) `True` values in `boolean mask`:

```
print ((houseprice.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, float)) & 
        houseprice.isnull()).any().sum())
2
```

Answer (score 7):

Only thing I could think of is to check if elements are `float` because `np.nan` is of type `float` and is null.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1., None, np.nan]), dtype=np.object)

print(df)

      A
0     1
1  None
2   NaN
```

Then we test if both `float` and `isnull`

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float)) & df.A.isnull()

0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```